# Sencha Touch: Changing line marker colors

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-charts

Is there any way to change the colors of marker in Sencha Touch charts. How can I change the marker colors in Sencha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the colors of markers in `ThemeList.js` in Sencha Charts. Please refer to [this following link for clarification.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?175291-Change-marker-color&p=718093&posted=1